# Showing $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}, \: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I will like to show

$|x|=\sqrt{x^{2}}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I define $f(x):=\sqrt{x^{2}}$ and $g(x):=|x|$.

For $x \ge 0$ I have $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}}=x$

For $x < 0$ I have $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}}=-x$

This is exactly what $g(x)$ does. So $f(x)=g(x)$.

Is this a valid proof?

Kind regards,

Comment: Yes, if you are sure about the equations used like $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ for $x<0$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I assume this is the case.

Comment: You may also consider $x^{2} = |x|^{2}$.